# What is wrong with this ASP.Net and Fiddler example?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am using Visual Studio 2012 RC. I am using the default routes and have the following Web API controller:

```
public class FooController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/foo
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/foo/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/foo
    public string Post(string abc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("value: {0}", abc);
        return "foo" + abc;
    }

    // PUT api/foo/5
    public void Put(int id, string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/foo/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

I wanted to do a simple test of POST in Fiddler, so I have

Request Headers

User-Agent: Fiddler

Content-Type: application/json

Request Body

{"abc": "def"}

When I debug the request, the parameter abc comes in as null, not "def". Is there something wrong with my Fiddler syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) By default, simple types are taken from the URI. To read a simple type from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter.

```
public string Post([FromBody] string abc)
```

(2) '{"abc": "def"}' defines an object with a property named "abc" - to send a JSON string, the request body should just be "def"

Comment: Figured out that it should be =def in Fiddler, instead of "def". I posted an answer with more details about what I had missed.

Comment: Ah, I must be just waking up. Cuong Le answered my question yesterday, but has since removed his answer from my post. He posted his own question, to which you, Mike, answered. And the answer was your blog post. I didn't notice that until just now.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from a link on the ASP.Net Web API site [sending-html-form-data](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_simple_types) , which turns out to be Mike's blog post (I didn't realize that at first). The Web API team has made a few decisions with parameter binding that are quite different from normal MVC controllers.

The correct syntax for sending "simple types" is

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostSimple([FromBody] string value)
{
// code goes here
```

And in Fiddler, you put

```
=def          //THIS CANNOT HAVE QUOTES AND = IS MANDATORY
```

OK, so here are the parts that work very differently from MVC.

1. You must use [FromBody], as Mike says.
2. You can only have 1 parameter. If you want more than 1 parameter, you have 2 choices: i) use url query parameters, instead of request body or ii) use a complex object (i.e. your own class).
3. The request body should be a simple =def and cannot use named parameters.