# posting json from fiddler leaves empty value to apicontroller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am trying to post some json data via fiddler, this is what I have in the header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost
Content-Length: 1176
```

body:

```
 [{
    'rows': [
        {
            'country': 'UK',
            'description': 'this is a desc',
            'gezien': true,
            'Count': 3,
            'url': 'een/twee',
            'stam': 'blabla',
            'kanaal': 'NOS'
        },
        {
            'url': 'drie/vier',
            'stam': 'divers',
            'kanaal': 'SRV'
        }

    ],
    'skip': 0,
    'take': 10,
    'total': 100
}]
```

My url is:

```
http://localhost/api/jason
```

c# controller web api action:

```
// POST api/default1
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    parseJson(value);

}

private void parseJson(object json)
{
    if (json!=null)
    {
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyItem>>(json.ToString());
    }
}
```

When I execute I the value is empty and I get a 204 httpcode. How do I call this from fiddler so it returns a jsonvalue in the value variable?

Comment: Did you look for duplicate questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864029/what-is-wrong-with-this-asp-net-and-fiddler-example

Comment: You don't need `value=` at the beginning of your body.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get this working.

Replace all the " in JSON with \". Then remove `value=` from the request body. Wrap everything inside "". Your request body should be like this.

```
"[
  {
    \"id\": \"5241585099662481339\",
    \"displayName\": \"Music\",
    \"name\": \"music\",
    \"slug\": \"music\",
    \"imageUrl\": \"http://kcdn3.klout.com/static/images/music-1333561300502.png\"
  },
  {
    \"id\": \"6953585193220490118\",
    \"displayName\": \"Celebrities\",
    \"name\": \"celebrities\",
    \"slug\": \"celebrities\",
    \"imageUrl\": \"http://kcdn3.klout.com/static/images/topics/celebrities_b32741b6703151cc7bd85fba24c44c52.png\"
  },
  {
    \"id\": \"5757029936226020304\",
    \"displayName\": \"Entertainment\",
    \"name\": \"entertainment\",
    \"slug\": \"entertainment\",
    \"imageUrl\": \"http://kcdn3.klout.com/static/images/topics/Entertainment_7002e5d2316e85a2ff004fafa017ff44.png\"
  },
  {
    \"id\": \"3718\",
    \"displayName\": \"Saturday Night Live\",
    \"name\": \"saturday night live\",
    \"slug\": \"saturday-night-live\",
    \"imageUrl\": \"http://kcdn3.klout.com/static/images/icons/generic-topic.png\"
  },
  {
    \"id\": \"8113008320053776960\",
    \"displayName\": \"Hollywood\",
    \"name\": \"hollywood\",
    \"slug\": \"hollywood\",
    \"imageUrl\": \"http://kcdn3.klout.com/static/images/topics/hollywood_9eccd1f7f83f067cb9aa2b491cd461f3.png\"
  }
]"
```

That should work but it sounds horrible because this is not how web API is supposed to be used. You should let web API do the binding for you instead of you manually doing it. If you change the action method signature to `public void Post(MyItem[] value)`, then you can just post the JSON (without value=) and it will give you the list of `MyItem` right away. You don't need to use JSON.NET and parse the JSON yourself.

UPDATE

A couple of options, if you want to retain the JSON as-is

(1) Bind it to a class (complex type).

(2) If you want to read the JSON as string, do something like this.

```
public async Task Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    string requestContent = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // use requestContent variable here
}
```

Comment: I need to keep the json format the same( I updated it see above)